# Fragment List view Android Retrieveing data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am having problem to retrieve data from parse in swipe able and in activity it is retrieving but in swipe able tabs it is not able and saying error in string . I knows how to implement tabs but having problem to retrieve data

Holiday activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_holiday);

    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.dl);
    ParseObject.registerSubclass(Holiday.class);


    mAdapter = new HolidayAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Holiday>());

    ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.holiday_list);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




    updateData();
}
public void updateData() {
    ParseQuery<Holiday> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Holiday.class);

    query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Holiday>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Holiday> holidays, com.parse.ParseException e) {

            if (holidays != null) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < holidays.size(); i++) {
                    mAdapter.add(holidays.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

i want to retrieve data it in tab

TabPageAdapter

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:

        return new Holiday();
    case 1:

        return new Main();

    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2; //No of Tabs you can give your number of tabs
}


}
```

Is there any way so that I can retrieve the data from parse in tabs instead of activity`enter code here`

Comment: What is the error? Could you please post the logcat?

Comment: The error is that the line becomes res of array in holiday activity and sorry I debug the app everytime to and run it on my phone via apk file